# How to keep menu item highlighted when in that view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the menu item to be highlighted of the current view that we're in.  As of now, `Item 2` is hardcoded to be active and color yellow because that's the view the user will land on upon loading the website.

If the user wants to go to `Item 3`, then `Item 3` should be yellow while `Item 1` and `Item 2` remain in their normal color state.

In the console, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: a.getElementsByClassName is not a function` which really didn't make sense to me but I guess this is where the problem stems from?

I've ran through so many examples online and tried many different suggestions but none of them seem to work.  What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

```js
(function () {
    console.log("inside function");

    let a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    let b = a.getElementsByClassName("active");
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
}());
```

```css
a.active {
      background-color: #ffff00;
      font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav container">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="user-navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li>
              <a href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>

          <li>
              <a href="#" class="active">Item 2</a>
          </li>

          <li>
              <a href="#">Item 3</a>
          </li>

      </ul>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of HTML elements (even if is just one), so you can't use `getElementsByClassName()` on a collection of elements, you must use it on a single element, maybe looping through `a`, and using `a[0]`...

Comment: `a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')` populates `a` with an Array (or live collection of HTML elements).  You aren't dereferencing the Array: `a[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElements...`.

`getElementsByTagName()` will return an array.. So you can not use `getElementsByClassName()` on it.. And that is the reason you are getting `Uncaught TypeError: a.getElementsByClassName is not a function` error.

Read more about [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

See the Snippet below:

```js
(function () {
    let a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            let current = document.querySelectorAll("a.active");
            current[0].classList.remove("active");
            this.classList.add("active");
        });
    }
}());
```

```css
a.active {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-nav container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="user-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="active">Item 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/6n42oc01/) also..

Comment: thanks man, appreciate it.  I noticed you never used the variable `b` but some how it runs fine.  Why so?

Comment: You actually don't need variable `b` because you are querying same inside the click handler. Forgot to remove it while cleaning up..

Comment: You got it buddy!